# How to move javascript if conditions to external file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scripting

Working on a script to transfer data between some software, in this script I have an if condition to ignore some particular fields that do not need to be transferred. Because of this I have a condition that looks something like:

```
if(
    object.field == "_Field1" ||
    object.field == "_Field2" ||
    object.field == "_Field3" ||
    object.field == "_Field4" 
...
) { ... }
```

However there are quite a few of these fields and more will likely emerge so I would like to move these fields to an external (text, or js?) file for easier maintenance and readability, how can I accomplish this without moving the if? Ideally I would like to be able to have another script which will write to this file when it needs to add a new field so the file should be just the comparisons.

Comment: Create a class, then pass you conditions as parameters in a function. You can then create an instance if the class in the 'external' file and execute the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the fields that you want to ignore on array and just remove them befor the actual object send:

```js
const ignoredFields=['_Field2','_Field2','_Field3','_Field4'] 
// or you can read them from a file

const mustIgnore = ({field})=>
  return ignoredFields.includes(field)
```

and now you can use `mustIgnore` dynamically without changing or adding if statement

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a function that did this evaluation and returned the result.  Something like this:

```
function isObjectOneOfSpecificFieldSubsets(object) {
    return (
        object.field == "_Field1" ||
        object.field == "_Field2" ||
        object.field == "_Field3" ||
        object.field == "_Field4" 
    )
}
```

Then your code above would become:

```
if(isObjectOneOfSpecificFieldSubsets(object)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your problem well but you could:

- have a file that only contains the list of fields you want to check:

```js
const FIELDS = [
  "_Field1",
  "_Field2",
  ...
]
```

- have a file with a util:

```js
const doFieldsCheckCondition = (field) => {
  ...
  for (let tmp_field of FIELDS) {
    ...
  }
}
```

- and then use this function in your original script:

```js
if (doFieldsCheckCondition(field)) {...}
```